cumulative sumifs with multiple criteria
This is a sample data for this question.
library(data.table);
sampleDT=data.table(sortcol1=c("Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv"),sortcol2=c("26g","A8q","A8q","A8q","A8q","A8q","F20z","K12s","K12s","K12s","M12g","M15h","T9c"," 26g"," 26g","A8q","A8q","A8q","F20z","K12s","K25h","M12g","M12g","M15h","M15h","N22p","N22p","A8q","A8q","F20z","M12g","M12g","N22p","N22p","A8q","K12s","K12s","M12g","N15z","N15z","N15z","N15z","N22p"," 26g","A8q","F20z","F20z","K12s","K12s","K25h","N15z","T9c","T9c"," 26g","A8q","F20z","M12g","M12g","M15h","M15h","M15h","M15h","N15z","N15z","N22p"," 26g","A8q","A8q","K25h","K25h","K25h","M15h","T9c","K12s","K25h","K25h","M12g","N15z","N22p","N22p","N22p","A8q","F20z","K12s","K12s","K12s","M15h","N15z","T9c","T9c"," 26g","A8q","K12s","M12g","M12g","M12g","M15h","N15z","N22p","T9c"),sortcol3=c(52024,5149,17725,52024,71627,71627,17725,5149,5149,121714,121714,5149,52024,17725,71627,5149,52024,71627,241210,16325,1966,1966,121714,1966,171721,121714,241210,5149,221324,171721,17725,71627,71627,241210,241210,5149,17725,16325,1966,5149,16325,121714,16325,1966,241210,17725,121714,16325,221324,52024,17725,171721,241210,1966,5149,16325,17725,121714,1966,121714,171721,221324,1966,71627,1966,221324,52024,71627,16325,221324,221324,241210,5149,17725,17725,221324,16325,17725,1966,71627,121714,52024,52024,5149,71627,221324,5149,241210,5149,71627,16325,1966,16325,5149,17725,52024,71627,5149,121714,121714));


This would be an ideal output. calc1 and calc2 to be calculated.
sampleDToutput=data.table(sortcol1=c("Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Ai","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Bs","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Ez","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Jd","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Nl","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Ok","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Oz","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Qm","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Rn","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv","Yv"),sortcol2=c("26g","A8q","A8q","A8q","A8q","A8q","F20z","K12s","K12s","K12s","M12g","M15h","T9c"," 26g"," 26g","A8q","A8q","A8q","F20z","K12s","K25h","M12g","M12g","M15h","M15h","N22p","N22p","A8q","A8q","F20z","M12g","M12g","N22p","N22p","A8q","K12s","K12s","M12g","N15z","N15z","N15z","N15z","N22p"," 26g","A8q","F20z","F20z","K12s","K12s","K25h","N15z","T9c","T9c"," 26g","A8q","F20z","M12g","M12g","M15h","M15h","M15h","M15h","N15z","N15z","N22p"," 26g","A8q","A8q","K25h","K25h","K25h","M15h","T9c","K12s","K25h","K25h","M12g","N15z","N22p","N22p","N22p","A8q","F20z","K12s","K12s","K12s","M15h","N15z","T9c","T9c"," 26g","A8q","K12s","M12g","M12g","M12g","M15h","N15z","N22p","T9c"),sortcol3=c(52024,5149,17725,52024,71627,71627,17725,5149,5149,121714,121714,5149,52024,17725,71627,5149,52024,71627,241210,16325,1966,1966,121714,1966,171721,121714,241210,5149,221324,171721,17725,71627,71627,241210,241210,5149,17725,16325,1966,5149,16325,121714,16325,1966,241210,17725,121714,16325,221324,52024,17725,171721,241210,1966,5149,16325,17725,121714,1966,121714,171721,221324,1966,71627,1966,221324,52024,71627,16325,221324,221324,241210,5149,17725,17725,221324,16325,17725,1966,71627,121714,52024,52024,5149,71627,221324,5149,241210,5149,71627,16325,1966,16325,5149,17725,52024,71627,5149,121714,121714),calc1=c(0,5149,10298,15447,20596,38321,56046,108070,160094,212118,283745,355372,477086,0,1966,3932,5898,11047,27372,45097,97121,168748,240375,362089,483803,655524,896734,0,5149,22874,94501,166128,337849,559173,0,1966,7115,12264,28589,44914,61239,78964,200678,0,1966,18291,36016,53741,105765,227479,399200,620524,861734,0,1966,3932,5898,7864,13013,29338,47063,118690,240404,362118,533839,0,5149,21474,73498,145125,366449,587773,809097,0,1966,18291,36016,53741,71466,143093,264807,0,5149,10298,15447,67471,119495,191122,262749,484073,0,1966,7115,12264,28589,44914,62639,114663,186290,308004),calc2=c(0,0,5149,22874,74898,146525,0,0,5149,10298,0,0,0,0,17725,0,5149,57173,0,0,0,0,1966,0,1966,0,121714,0,5149,0,0,17725,0,5149,0,0,5149,0,0,1966,7115,23440,0,0,0,0,17725,0,16325,0,0,0,171721,0,0,0,0,17725,0,1966,123680,295401,0,1966,0,0,0,52024,0,16325,237649,0,0,0,0,17725,0,0,0,1966,73593,0,0,0,5149,76776,0,0,0,5149,0,0,0,0,5149,22874,0,0,0,0));


(I)

calc1 is a cumulative sum of column sortcol3 after sorting of the 2 columns sortcol1 and sortcol3.
cumulative sum is only for unique items of sortcol1.
start with 2nd entry, 1st is always zero.
data is already ordered on the 2 columns(sometimes it is not), better if calc1 can be achieved without sorting.

(II)

calc2 is a cumulative sum of column sortcol3 after custom sorting of the 3 columns altogether sortcol1 , sortcol2 and sortcol3
cumulative sum is only for unique items concatenation of sortcol1 and sortcol2.
start with 2nd entry, 1st is always zero.
data is already ordered on all 3 columns(sometimes it is not), better if calc2 can be achieved without sorting.

Please if only data.table can be used.

If we resort for calc2 the order of calc1 will normally be shuffled, too. But the desired output shows them in the previous order. Is that really what's desired?

Yes, I agree. But is it possible to achieve calc1 without ordering the data? If no then, I will accept your answer.

Since you said order can't be assumed we have to sort the data, otherwise you will get different values for cumsum.

Let’s do 2 separate tables for each calc1 and calc2. But without ordering the data. langtang answer seems good.

An approach that cbinds two separate orders (keep in mind that calc1 is now out of order and does not correspond to its source-row any more)
library(data.table)

cbind(
  sampleDT[order(sortcol1, sortcol2, sortcol3), 
           .(sortcol3, calc2 = cumsum(c(0, sortcol3)[1:.N])),
           by = .(sortcol1, sortcol2)],
  sampleDT[order(sortcol1, sortcol3), 
           .(calc1 = cumsum(c(0, sortcol3)[1:.N])),
           by = sortcol1][,-1]
)
     sortcol1 sortcol2 sortcol3  calc2  calc1
       <char>   <char>    <num>  <num>  <num>
  1:       Ai      26g    52024      0      0
  2:       Ai      A8q     5149      0   5149
  3:       Ai      A8q    17725   5149  10298
  4:       Ai      A8q    52024  22874  15447
  5:       Ai      A8q    71627  74898  20596
  6:       Ai      A8q    71627 146525  38321
  7:       Ai     F20z    17725      0  56046
  8:       Ai     K12s     5149      0 108070
  9:       Ai     K12s     5149   5149 160094
 10:       Ai     K12s   121714  10298 212118
 11:       Ai     M12g   121714      0 283745
 12:       Ai     M15h     5149      0 355372
 13:       Ai      T9c    52024      0 477086
 14:       Bs      26g    17725      0      0
...


As @AndreWildberg points out, OP's own example of the desired solution (sampleDToutput) does not actually align with the OP's requirements for calc1 and calc2.
To align with the requirements for calc1 and calc2 (but not with sampleDToutput), you could do this:
f <- \(d) {list(
  d[,cumsum(c(0,sortcol3[-1]))],
  d[,cumsum(c(0,sortcol3[-1])), sortcol2]$V1
)}
  
sampleDT[order(sortcol3), c("calc1", "calc2"):=f(.SD), sortcol1]

